# JavaScript thinks is Thursday and Friday?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I wrote this code with JavaScript and a little jQuery to display some different messages depending on the day and universal time. Today (Thursday 17:00 GMT) I should see just one message but instead I see both, which is very odd because the second message is only supposed to show on Friday.

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var todaysDate = new Date();
    weekday = todaysDate.getDay();
    var universalhour = todaysDate.getUTCHours();

    if (weekday >= 0) {
        if (weekday <= 4) {
            if (universalhour >= 14) {
                if (universalhour < 23) {
                    $('div#announcements').append('<br />Test');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (weekday = 5) {
        if (universalhour >= 14) {
            if (universalhour < 20) {
                $('div#announcements').append('<br />Text');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/YdEgy/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if (weekday = 5) ` should probably be `if (weekday == 5)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typographical error.

Comment: @Pointy Ha! I think I'll go kill myself now...

Comment: @henryaaron It happens to all of us from time to time, don't feel bad about it haha.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is

```
if (weekday = 5) {  <-- you are assigning 5 to weekday
```

You want `==` or `===`